# EF Code First- Return Records from Many to Many Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I'm trying to get all records in an m:m table in a flat fashion with entity framework and linq.

Data Models:

```
public partial class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}

public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } = new Guid();

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the query in SQL which pulls back the dataset I'm looking for:

```
select g.GroupId, g.[Name], u.DisplayName, u.UserId 
from [Group] g, [User] u, [GroupUsers] gu
where g.GroupId = gu.Group_GroupId
and gu.User_UserId = u.UserId
order by g.[Name]
```

Here's what I'm trying in Linq, but I'm getting a self-referencing loop error:

```
using (RequestContext ctx = new RequestContext())
{
     return ctx.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Users).Include(x => x.Groups).ToList();
}
```

This seems like it should be relatively easy but I've found m:m in Entity Framework can be a bit tricky.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full error of `self-referencing loop error`, When I see this my assumption is that it's most likely caused by JSON Serialization.

Comment: x => x.Users will not work because the class is not enumerable.  Try instead db.Context.Users.Select(y => new { id = y.UserId, FirstName = y.FirstName, LastName = y.LastName, DisplayName = y.DisplayName});  Then you can add Groups if it works.

Comment: This is a very common error, covered in many questions on Stack Overflow. The solution is always: tweak the Json serializer settings *or* use a view model/DTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you defined your many-to-many as two *virtual* collections, without specifying the junction table!

You do realize, that if you don't fetch "groups with their users", but instead query a left outer join of groups and users (you call that a flat fashion), the group properties will be repeated over and over again for every user?

But hey, that's your decision, and it is up to you to convince your project leader that it is better to transfer the same group properties a hundred times instead of transferring them only once.

You were right, for a left outer join, you  need to do a `SelectMany`. I'm not sure why you decide to use `Include` instead of `Select`.

> When querying data always use **Select**, and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only use **Include** if you plan to update the fetched included data.

The reason for this is especially meaningful in a one-to-many relation. If you fetch "Schools with their Students", and School with Id 4 has 1000 Students, then you know that every Student of this School will have a foreign key with a value 4. What a waste to transfer this value 4 over a 1000 times!

One of the overloads of [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__) has a parameter `resultSelector`, which will take one `Group` and one `User` as input to create the result. This version is perfect for your needs

```
var result = dbContext.Groups.SelectMany(
    group => group.Users,
    (group, user) => new
    {
        // Select the Group properties you plan to use
        GroupId = group.GroupId,
        GroupName = group.Name,
        ...

        // Select the User properties you plan to use
        UserId = user.UserId,
        UserName = user.DisplayName,
        ...
    })

    // if desired do some ordering
    .OrderBy(joinedItem => joinedItem.GroupName);
```

Comment: Thank you Harald. This makes sense and worked perfectly. I'm a bit green with EF code first and Linq, so I appreciate your advice and the opportunity to learn.